# Jquery Remove All Event Handlers Inside Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have a div element with several elements inside it like buttons and so forth which have event handlers attached to them. I know its possible to go:

```
$("#button1").off()
```

To remove the handler for a button but I would like to do something like this if possible:

```
$("#div1").removeChildHandlers();
```

Is there a native function in JQuery to do this or would I have to loop them all the elements and remove 1 by 1?

Comment: is maybe `.find('button').off()` what are you looking for?

Comment: Nope something less specific

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all jQuery event handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377854/remove-all-jquery-event-handlers)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

jQuery will do the looping for you for just the direct children:

```
$("#div1").children().off();
```

or if you want all descendants:

```
$("#div1").find("*").off();
```

Comment: Thanks I think that covered just about all possibilities I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for this. I found it's hard to determine whether an event handler already exists without manually tracking it. Turning all the descendant handlers off allows me to just re-apply them right after. Likely not good for performance, but a quick solution is great to have!

Comment: what is the main difference between `$("#div1").children().off()` from `$("#div1").off()`?

Comment: @Malky.Kid - `$("#div1").off()` removes event handlers from only the `#div1` element itself.  `$("#div1").children().off()` operates on only the children of `#div` and does not operate on `#div` at all.  So, it depends upon which elements you want to operate on.

Comment: @jfriend00 my gratitude

Answer (score 4):

Does this help:

```
$("#div1").find('*').off();
```

Comment: Instead of `$("#div1").find('*')` one can use CSS selector `$("#div1 *")`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$("#div1 >* ").off();
```

Or:

```
$("#div1").find('button').off();
```

if you're talking about `<button>` elements

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the better practice and better performant option would be to attach the handler to the outside parent with the `on` method...

```
$("#div1").find("click", ".childButton", magicFunction);
```

Then to remove all listeners you can call `off` on just the parent element.

```
$("#div1").off();
```