# How do I remove all the event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventhandler

Can I remove all the event handlers even these handlers are not directly bond to it?

That's say I have a `#maincontainer`, which has a `#player`, which has a lot of `.card`, then I bind a click event handler to `#player`. Can I remove it from `#maincontainer`? And if other children or descendants of `#maincontainer` are bond to some other event handler, I want these handler to be removed, too.

Comment: Quick and dirty: `#maincontainer.innerHTML =  #maincontainer.innerHTML`.

Comment: You could use event delegation and only bind a listener to `#maincontainer` which you don’t need to remove.

Comment: @Teemu How does these tricks work?

Comment: That re-creates your HTML. Listeners from old elements are not attached to the new elements, assuming you've not inline listeners nor delegated listeners on the ancestors of `#maincontainer`.

Comment: @unicellular The above was actually a joke (it works in very limited conditions though). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945025/jquery-remove-all-event-handlers-inside-element , that probably suits better for your purposes.